# Spark HBaseTest not working

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

Trying to get the HBaseTest working on a spark setup on yarn in cluster mode with kerberos auth -

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn-cluster \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.HBaseTest \
--jars /apache/hbase/lib/*.jars \
--driver-class-path /apache/hbase/conf \
$SPARK_HOME/lib/spark-examples.jar \
myhbasetable
```

I end up getting -

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=35, exceptions:
Tue Jan 19 01:00:22 GMT-07:00 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@6515a0f9, java.io.IOException: Failed to find location, tableName=hbase:meta, row=myhbasetable,,00000000000000, reload=false
Tue Jan 19 01:00:50 GMT-07:00 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@6515a0f9, java.io.IOException: Enable/Disable failed
Tue Jan 19 01:01:16 GMT-07:00 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@6515a0f9, java.io.IOException: Enable/Disable failed
Tue Jan 19 01:01:43 GMT-07:00 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@6515a0f9, java.io.IOException: Enable/Disable failed
Tue Jan 19 01:02:09 GMT-07:00 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@6515a0f9, java.io.IOException: Enable/Disable failed
Tue Jan 19 01:02:37 GMT-07:00 2016, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@6515a0f9, java.io.IOException: Enable/Disable failed
```

EDIT:

I dont have the master ip in the hbase-site.xml, how can i find that ? I have the list of ips though. I was able to get it running with the spark-shell but not with spark-submit .. I get this error which I feel is related to authentication in someways -

```
16/01/19 18:45:39 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Call to 10.115.201.64:60000 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Call id=4, waitTime=38 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.io.IOException: Call to 10.115.201.64:60000 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Call id=4, waitTime=38 
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1607) 
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1633)
at ...
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more info on how you try to connect? I attach here an example hoping is usefull:

```
val hbaseOutConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
hbaseOutConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "list of ip's")
hbaseOutConf.set("hbase.zookeeper"+ ".property.clientPort","2181");
hbaseOutConf.set("hbase.master", "masterIP:60000");
hbaseOutConf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
hbaseOutConf.set("hbase.security.authentication", "kerberos");
```

Use UserGRoupInformation for the login from keytab

```
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(hbaseOutConf);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("user@---", keyTabPath);

HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(hbaseOutConf);
```

If you are in a Cloudera env check the following project :

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/08/apache-spark-comes-to-apache-hbase-with-hbase-spark-module/

Comment: I am just using this example class out of the box https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/HBaseTest.scala
I set the hbase conf through --driver-class-path as suggested in that example.

Comment: I dont have the master ip in the hbase-site.xml, how can i find that ? I have the list of ips though. I was able to get it running with the spark-shell but not with spark-submit .. I get this error which I feel is related to authentication in someways

Comment: on the shell if you run start-hbase.sh and after check the processes with jps on the machine where the master run you should see a process with name HMaster , moreover there is a web UI accessible at IPoftheMaster:60010/